# portrait camera orientation on galaxy tab

Tags: android, camera, rotation, preview, android-camera

I am developing on/for a Samsung Galaxy Tab (7inches). My application has to be in portrait mode only, i.e i have locked it to portrait mode in my application and in the device settings. The problem is when i try to rotate the camera preview, it is currently rotated 90 degrees in the wrong direction.

Right now this is my surfaceCreated

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        //camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); 
        parameters.setRotation(90);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
        camera.release();
    }
}
```

The camera.setDisplayOrientation(90) does not seem to be working (it does nothing, which is why i have commented it away). However the parameters.setRotation(90) DOES IN FACT GET THE JOB DONE! but it creates an ugly "stripe" of "flickering colors" along the side of the application. setDisplayOrientation() should work for me, since i am running android api 8 (Froyo 2.2)!!

There is a thread on google about problems pertaining to rotational issues http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193#c26, but to the best of my knowledge it does not suggest anything for my problem.

Any and all solutions pertaining to this problem will be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Samsung Galaxy tab:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
    params.set("orientation", "portrait");
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    try
    {
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    }
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is designed to only take Portrait photos, then the simplest thing to do is to just rotate the image data after you've taken the photo, and not worry about the camera settings. I'm not sure if the Tab is buggy (I've never tried to rotate the camera preview) but rotating the image after you've taken the shot is very simple... the problem is only if you need to know which way the device was being held when the picture was taken. If that's not a concern for you, then don't fret over it :)

Comment: Rotating the taken picture is not a big deal, but i would like the preview to be the same as the picture taken. Usability and all that ;) Taking the picture is not the problem it is the previews rotation.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I make this code and test on Galaxy Tab. The code works well

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    camera = Camera.open();

    try {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
        {                       
         camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } else {
          Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
          parameters.setRotation(90);       
          camera.setParameters(parameters); 
        }

        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        camera.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work for me. =(. It is very similar to the code i had already, but i like the fancy IF statement! I feel like this code should work (it does not make sense that setDisplayOrientation does nothing for my camera!), and yet it does not. Thank you so much for the answer.